# iOS self sizing table views inside self sizing table views

Tags: ios, swift

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quy1H.png)
I have a tableView with X number of cells, every cell has 1 table view with N number of cells.
How to make every x cell fits the the content size of it's sub tableView.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use table view with sections, so your X number of cells will be the number of sections in this case, and N number of cell will be number of rows in that section.

```
    //MARK: TableView Delegate
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return X
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "YourIdentifier") as? YourTableViewCell
        return cell

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return numberOfRows
    }
```

Hope that is what you need.

Comment: the problem is I need to display different cells related to different sections in the subtable view  related to x cell.
this is the design I want to create: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/quy1H.png